# MSSQL procedure to insert rows and return the inserted row/return value... throws exception when called

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am primarily a Java developer with some level of oracle DB experience. I am having to use MSSQL server 2008 R2 for one project. I took a quick tutorial of mssql server on udemy and started creating functions and procedures.

The problem is three fold,

a)   i need to pass a few values to a procedure or a function and insert them in a table and return.

i have read online that functions cannot be used for inserting into existing tables .. rather they only insert into temp tables.. is this true ? can you not insert into a table and return the row inserted in a function on MSSQL server? I used the below procedure anyways.

```
USE [KingsBayY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

alter PROCEDURE test_fn_transaction_insert_log @receipt varchar(25), @amount varchar(25), @stdt varchar(25), 
@enddt varchar(25)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO [TransactionLog] ( TimeStamp, CashierID, Total,RecurringStartDate, 
RecurringStopDate, CustomerID, ReceiptNumber, Voided, Attendee, ItemLookupCode)
SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS [TimeStamp], tr.CashierID, @amount, @stdt,@enddt,c.ID,tr.ReceiptNumber,
tr.Voided,it.ItemLookupCode, tr.Comment
from [Transaction] tr, TransactionEntry trent, Item it, Customer c
     where trent.TransactionID = tr.ID
     and trent.ItemID = it.ID
     and c.ID=tr.CustomerID
     and tr.ReceiptNumber=@receipt
--condition to ensure no duplicates are entered  and [TransactionLog].ID not in (select ID from [TransactionLog] where [TransactionLog].ID=tr.ID)

GO
```

As of now, When i try to call this procedure in Java as below, it throws an exception

```
public String saveTr(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
    try
    {
        SqlServerConn conn = new SqlServerConn();
        connect=conn.getConnection();
        String SQL = String.format("Exec test_fn_transaction_insert_log ?,?,?,?");  
        pstmt = connect.prepareStatement(SQL);
        pstmt.setString(1, a);
        pstmt.setString(2, b);
        pstmt.setString(3, c);
        pstmt.setString(4, d);
        pstmt.executeQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return "fail";
    }
    //ArrayList<Transactions> list=getrowFromResultSet2(rs);

    return "success";
}
```

i get this exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
```

b)  in the above procedure, i need to return the row just inserted. how can i do this? or atleast get a return code?

c) is this even the best way of writing this procedure for the requirement? can functions be used ?

Answer (score 0):

a) That's correct, functions, in the sense that SQL refers to them as, cannot be used to perform any data modification. However what youre looking for is a stored procedure. In the Java/C# lingo, a stored procedure is still basically a function, it's just distingished in SQL in terms of what it is or isnt allowed to perform.

b) If you need the row returned, you have two options. The first, since you're using SQL Server 2008 or more recent, you can use the OUTPUT clause. You can read about it on MSDN, but the idea is between your insert and the select, you just slide in an OUTPUT statement that takes the stuff you're currently inserting, and selects it out. Alternatively, if you dont want to use the output clause, you can, after your insert, just make a select statement which returns the values associated with the primary key(s) you just inserted

c) see a. Procedure is the way to go.

EDIT: link to MSDN OUTPUT documentation. Specifically look at how it works with inserts.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Here's a good article on the summary of function and procedure differences in SQL

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/7EDL150912-Difference-between-Stored-Procedure-and-Function-in-SQL-Server.html